# Code cleaning in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, optimization

This is a question that is completely a matter of opinion. But it might also be a question about stupidity from my side. Its working fine both ways. But I want to find out what people think.

```
    public IQueryable<User> Users {
        get {
            return context.Users;
        }
    }
```

There we go... Thats a function that is returning all users from the EntityFramework context, its in my repository. context.Users is a IObjectSet btw.

```
    public User GetUserById(int userId) {
        return context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);
    }
```

This is an example of another function in my repository. As I do here I use context.Users.
I might aswell write it like this.

```
    public User GetUserById(int userId) {
        return Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);
    }
```

I want to use the last one cause the code looks cleaner. But will this effect the performance in any way at all?! This is propably a stupid question... But Im abit new to working with bigger projects where every small detail could count. (I know that entity framework might be the wrong way to go but Its not my call)

Comment: "prestanda" = "performance"? ( http://www.woxikon.de/swe/prestanda.php )

Comment: yes. "prestanda" = "performance"? (sorry for bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're describing a layer of indirection/abstraction between your consuming code and Entity Framework. I consider this a good thing. I actually modify the T4 POCO templates to automatically generate what you have in #1 and generate an interface that just returns IQueryables.

Many modern ORMs offer LINQ support these days...and it's nice to know that the rest of your code doesn't have to know what ORM it's talking to...in case you decide to move away from Entity Framework at some point.

To answer your question about performance: no I don't think it will adversely affect performance. There are a few extra CIL statements being generated in your compiled code, but that's about it.

Comment: Thanks for comment, didnt think of that. That in itself is a good thing.